# How to match a single quote in sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed, escaping

How to match a single quote in sed if the expression is enclosed in single quotes:

```
sed -e '...'
```

For example need to match this text:

```
'foo'
```

Comment: the tag [sed] is more or less incorrect, since the question could be about e.g. awk without any changes in content. It should be 'shell', but I can't retag.

Comment: @TimB: shell-quoting is a completely new tag, and redundant since "shell", "escaping" are more than enough. "Escaping" has been used for decades (close to 40 years) when one strips characters from their special meaning in shell… and the question was about escaping a quote.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can either use:

```
"texta'textb" (APOSTROPHE inside QUOTATION MARKs)
```

or

```
'texta'\''textb' (APOSTROPHE text APOSTROPHE, then REVERSE SOLIDUS, APOSTROPHE, then APOSTROPHE more text APOSTROPHE)
```

I used unicode character names. REVERSE SOLIDUS is more commonly known as backslash.

In the latter case, you close your apostrophe, then shell-quote your apostrophe with a backslash, then open another apostrophe for the rest of the text.

Answer (score 50):

As noted in the comments to the question, it's not really about sed, but how to include a quote in a quoted string in a shell (e.g. bash).

To clarify a previous answer, you need to escape the quote with a backslash, but you can't do that within a single-quoted expression.  From the bash man page:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes
>   preserves the literal value of each
>   character within the quotes.  A single
>   quote may not occur between single
>   quotes, even when preceded by a
>   backslash.

Therefore, you need to terminate the quoted expression, insert the escaped quote, and start a new quoted expression.  The shell's quote removal does not add any extra spaces, so in effect you get string concatenation.

So, to answer the original question of how to single quote the expression 'foo', you would do something like this:

```
sed -e '...'\''foo'\''...'
```

(where '...' is the rest of the sed expression).

Overall, for the sake of readability, you'd be much better off changing the surrounding quotes to double quotes if at all possible:

```
sed -e "...'foo'..."
```

[As an example of the potential maintenance nightmare of the first (single quote) approach, note how StackOverflow's syntax highlighting colours the quotes, backslashes and other text -- it's definitely not correct.]

Comment: A fantastic in-depth explanation, thank you

Answer (score 1):

For sed, a very simple solution is to change the single quotation format to a double quote.

For a given variable that contains single quotes

```
var="I'm a string with a single quote"
```

If double quotes are used for sed, this will match the single quote.

```
echo $var | sed "s/'//g"
Im a string with a single quote
```

Rather than single quotes, which will hang

```
echo $var | sed 's/'//g'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `[']` to match a literal single quote without needing to do any shell quoting tricks.

```
myvar="stupid computers can't reason about life"
echo "$myvar" | sed -e "s/[']t//"
```

Outputs:

```
stupid computers can reason about life
```

Comment: **...wut.** If you're already double-quoting, you never need `[']`, because you can already just embed `'` literally as is; if you're single-quoting, you can't use either. Ergo, you never need `[']`. This answer is less useful than the hairball our Maine Coon just puked all over the floor.