# Escape single and double quote using sed. geed, find, xargs

Tags: regex, replace, sed, escaping

I have a command similiar this this one:

```
find ./ -type f | xargs gsed -i -r 's/[$][A-Za-z_\'"]/testing
```

I would like put this command to work. Unfortunally the single and double quotes breaks the command. How can I escape this strings and put this command to work?

This question isnt the same as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517632/how-do-i-escape-double-and-single-quotes-in-sed-bash) because I have a single quote inside the **[**. But if a littler modification solves the problem works I would like to know.

I had tried several different ways using @, #, \, but no success yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

take a look this:

```
kent$  cat file
''''''
""""""

kent$  sed 's/\x27/single /g;s/\x22/double /g' file
single single single single single single 
double double double double double double
```

so , change your cmd into:

```
find ./ -type f | xargs gsed -i -r 's/[$][A-Za-z_\x22\x27]/testing'
```

**note** I didn't check if your find/xargs part ok, just for the single/double quote part.

Comment: This did not work for me (no error but nothing substituted). I am on a mac.

Comment: @rrr yours is bsd sed. you don't have the `-i` option. read man page for the in-place sub.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a single quote in single quotes. You can:

1. End the single quotes and then use a backslashed quote: `'...'\'`
2. End the single quotes and then use a single quote in double quotes: `'...'"'"`

Comment: 3. Use different quote types for wrapping the expression than the one you are substituting. (i.e. use single quotes in double quotes).    If you wrap with double quotes: `sed "s/'/bla/"` the single quote `'` will be replaced with `bla` with no need for escaping. (I'm on a mac)

Comment: @rrr: Double quotes might require adding more backslashes as they might start expanding some substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try putting the sed script in double quotes and escape what needs to be escaped

```
gsed -i -r "s/[$][A-Za-z_'\"]/testing/"
```