# How to use variables in a command in sed?

Tags: unix, sed

I have `abc.sh`:

```
exec $ROOT/Subsystem/xyz.sh
```

On a Unix box, if I print `echo $HOME` then I get `/HOME/COM/FILE`.

I want to replace `$ROOT` with `$HOME` using sed.

Expected Output:

```
exec /HOME/COM/FILE/Subsystem/xyz.sh
```

I tried, but I'm not getting the expected output:

```
sed  's/$ROOT/"${HOME}"/g' abc.sh > abc.sh.1
```

---

Addition:

If I have `abc.sh`

```
exec $ROOT/Subsystem/xyz.sh $ROOT/ystem/xyz1.sh
```

then with

```
sed "s|\$INSTALLROOT/|${INSTALLROOT}|" abc.sh
```

it is only replacing first `$ROOT`, i.e., output is coming as

```
exec /HOME/COM/FILE/Subsystem/xyz.sh $ROOT/ystem/xyz1.sh
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace a string in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script)

Comment: @tripleee While I'm certain that this would be a duplicate of numerous other questions, the one that you've pointed to isn't the best one since it doesn't contain slashes in the variable.  All answers therein use `/` as the separator.  Obvious stuff, I know but leaves room for a better (duplicate) question.

Comment: The question contains several errors, so we would have to close it as a duplicate of three different canonicals. These are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/using-different-delimiters-in-sed-commands-and-range-addresses, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506303/escape-dollar-sign-in-regexp-for-sed

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Say:

```
sed "s|\$ROOT|${HOME}|" abc.sh
```

Note:

- Use double quotes so that the shell would expand variables.
- Use a separator different than `/` since the replacement contains `/`
- Escape the `$` in the pattern since you don't want to expand it.

EDIT: In order to replace all occurrences of `$ROOT`, say

```
sed "s|\$ROOT|${HOME}|g" abc.sh
```

Comment: This completely did the trick. In case it helps anyone out, I did something like this:

sed "s|@@ALF_INSTALL_DIR|${ALF_INSTALL_DIR}|g" files/tomcat/alfresco-global.properties.template > files/tomcat/alfresco-global.properties

The variable contains "/" because it has a path to it (fwiw).

Answer (score 28):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's|$ROOT|'"${HOME}"'|g' abc.sh > abc.sh.1
```

Comment: thanks, I had to add | sed 's/[{}]//g' to remove the brackets, but otherwise it worked

Comment: This is the only working approach that helped me with the following replacement: `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/UUID=[A-Fa-f0-9-]*/UUID='"${new_uuid}"'/2' /etc/fstab | sudo tee /etc/fstab2 > /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

This may also can help

```
input="inputtext"
output="outputtext"
sed "s/$input/${output}/" inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: This could be problematic if input or output contains a slash

Comment: I would want to have date variable and it looks like 




    currentDate=$date
    sed -i '12s|\(.*\)|<h1 style="text-align:center;">My Report</h1><h3>Executed by: My 
      Build tool </h3><h3>Executed on: $currentDate</script></h2>\1|' <<path to HTML 
       file>>


As we see, currentDate is being used in `sed -i` command. Is it possible to make it work ?

Answer (score -1):

The safe for a special chars workaround from https://www.baeldung.com/linux/sed-substitution-variables with improvement for `\` char:

```
#!/bin/bash
to="/foo\\bar#baz"
echo "str %FROM% str" | sed "s#%FROM%#$(echo ${to//\\/\\\\} | sed 's/#/\\#/g')#g"
```