# sed with arbitrary variables that might contain slashes

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to use sed in the following-ish way:

```
VAR=`echo $STRING | sed s/$TOKEN/$REPLACEMENT/`
```

Unfortunately, I've come upon a case where $REPLACEMENT might possibly contain slashes. This causes the bash to complain, as it (the shell) potentially expands it to something like this:

```
#given $VAR=I like bananas, $TOKEN=bananas, and $REPLACEMENT=apples/oranges
VAR=`echo I like bananas | sed s/bananas/apples/oranges/`
```

So now sed is given an invalid argument with too many /'s. Is there any good way to handle that?

Comment: You should replace old and obsoleted back-tics with parentheses `$(...)` example: `VAR=$(echo $STRING | sed s/$TOKEN/$REPLACEMENT/)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed command : How to use variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151954/sed-command-how-to-use-variable)

Comment: It's worse than that. If $TOKEN contains RE metacharacters (`.`, `*`, etc.) then sed will evaluate those too. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any separator you like. `"s!$TOKEN!$REPLACEMENT!"` and `"s%$TOKEN%$REPLACEMENT%"` are popular alternatives.

Of course, in the general case, if the input could contain any characters whatsoever, you're back to square one. You could switch to a language which doesn't mix code and data so frivolously... including, in fact, the shell itself;

```
echo "${VAR/$TOKEN/$REPLACEMENT}"
```

(This is a Bash extension, though. It is available in some other shells, but not in classic Bourne shell.)

Comment: Another good option is non-printable ascii control characters that are especially unlikely to appear in strings: `printf -v foo 's\x01%s\x01%s\x01' "searchstring" "replacsestring"; echo "$string" | sed -e "$foo"`

Comment: @thatotherguy intriguing idea, but I'm hesitant to recommend that, as it's bound to break on various `sed` implementations out there.

Comment: I doubt it. This would both violate POSIX, and would be harder to implement in C than simply allowing it.

Comment: At least on OSX I was unable to get it to work, although the stumbling point was that `printf` didn't seem to want to accept control characters in the form `\x01`.  Using a literal control-A character allowed me to work around that.  But anyway, it's going to be hard to come up with something completely portable (which would not be more convoluted than simply using e.g. Perl instead).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix

```
VAR="I like bananas"
TOKEN="bananas"
REPLACEMENT="apples/oranges"
echo $VAR |sed "s@$TOKEN@$REPLACEMENT@"

I like apples/oranges
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably use sed for this as:

1. you typically can't find a character that is guaranteed not to be
   in any of the $TOKEN or $REPLACEMENT strings, and
2. sed cannot search for a string - it ALWAYS searches for regular expressions and
   so any RE metacharacters in $TOKEN will be evaluated as such and you
   cannot reliably implement code to escape them (despite what many
   people have attempted).

So, just use awk:

```
VAR=$(echo "$STRING" | awk -v t="$TOKEN" -v r="$REPLACEMENT" 'idx=index($0,t) {$0 = substr($0,1,idx-1) r substr($0,idx+length(t))} 1')
```

That will work for absolutely any character in any of the 3 strings except a newline in $STRING.

Without the `echo` it will handle a newline in $STRING too:

```
VAR=$(awk -v s="$STRING" -v t="$TOKEN" -v r="$REPLACEMENT" '
BEGIN {
    if (idx = index(s,t))
        s = substr(s,1,idx-1) r substr(s,idx+length(t))
    print s
}')
```