# Trouble with using sed command to update key value of config file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Having following bash script to update key value of my config file

```
#!/bin/bash

ipaddr="192.168.0.1"
path="my/binary/file/path/version_op.bin"

sed -i "s/\("IP_ADDR" *= *\).*/\1$ipaddr/" config.txt

sed -i "s/\("PATH_N_FILENAME" *= *\).*/\1${path}/" config.txt
```

config file (config.txt) content

```
IP_ADDR=192.168.0.1

PATH_N_FILENAME=NO_PATH
```

Above scripts working fine for only update `IP_ADDR` but when i enable `sed` for `PATH_N_FILENAME` then it show me following error.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unknown option to `s'
```

might be this issue occurs because of `path` variable contain `/` in path and it put `sed` in  confusion state.but what ever issue , still i could not find it.

Have any one idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Use a different separator.  This is a __FAQ__.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed command : How to use variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151954/sed-command-how-to-use-variable)

Comment: @devnull you are right using different separator it will fix.t try as follows `sed -i "s|\("PATH_N_FILENAME" *= *\).*|\1${path}|" input.txt` and it works fine...Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

use single-quote in sed command section :

```
sed -i 's/\("IP_ADDR" *= *\).*/\1$ipaddr/' config.txt
```