# Escape dollar sign in regexp for sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

*I will introduce what my question is about before actually asking - feel free to skip this section!*

**Some background info about my setup**

To update files manually in a software system, I am creating a bash script to remove all files that are not present in the new version, using diff:

```
for i in $(diff -r old new 2>/dev/null | grep "Only in old" | cut -d "/" -f 3- | sed "s/: /\//g"); do echo "rm -f $i" >> REMOVEOLDFILES.sh; done
```

This works fine. However, apparently my files often have a dollar sign ($) in the filename, this is due to some permutations of the GWT framework. Here is one example line from the above created bash script:

```
rm -f var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/ExampleFile$3$1$1$1$2$1$1.class
```

Executing this script would not remove the wanted files, because bash reads these as argument variables. Hence I have to escape the dollar signs with "\$".

**My actual question**

I now want to add a sed-Command in the aforementioned pipeline, replacing this dollar sign. As a matter of fact, sed also reads the dollar sign as special character for regular expressions, so obviously I have to escape it as well.
But somehow this doesn't work and I could not find an explanation after googling a lot.

Here are some variations I have tried:

```
echo "Bla$bla" | sed "s/\$/2/g"        # Output: Bla2
echo "Bla$bla" | sed 's/$$/2/g'        # Output: Bla
echo "Bla$bla" | sed 's/\\$/2/g'       # Output: Bla
echo "Bla$bla" | sed 's/@"\$"/2/g'     # Output: Bla
echo "Bla$bla" | sed 's/\\\$/2/g'      # Output: Bla
```

The desired output in this example should be "Bla2bla".
What am I missing?
I am using GNU sed 4.2.2

**EDIT**

I just realized, that the above example is wrong to begin with - the echo command already interprets the $ as a variable and the following sed doesn't get it anyway... Here a proper example:

1. Create a textfile `test` with the content `bla$bla`
2. `cat test` gives `bla$bla`
3. `cat test | sed "s/$/2/g"` gives `bla$bla2`
4. `cat test | sed "s/\$/2/g"` gives `bla$bla2`
5. `cat test | sed "s/\\$/2/g"` gives `bla2bla`

Hence, the last version is the answer. Remember: *when testing, first make sure your test is correct, before you question the test object........*

Comment: `echo "Bla\\\$bla" | sed "s/\\\\\\$/2/g"`. I guess it will work if the actual strings contain a `$` as a part of a string literal.

Comment: Don't iterate over a file (or command output) with `for`. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: I upvoted this question because it's a great example of how to ask a good question: showing effort, research and explaining how the specific question fits into the overall goal. Welcome to Stack Overflow, Captain.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan thanks :-)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew changing the actual string is my goal - not the solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are other problems with your script, but file names containing `$` are not a problem if you properly quote the argument to `rm` in the resulting script.

```
echo "rm -f '$i'" >> REMOVEOLDFILES.sh
```

or using `printf`, which makes quoting a little nicer and is more portable:

```
printf "rm -f '%s'" "$i" >> REMOVEOLDFILES.sh
```

(Note that I'm addressing the real problem, not necessarily the question you asked.)

Comment: Thanks for the good idea and also for addressing my actual problem :-) Unfortunately bash will still read something like "$1" as arguments, even if it is within quotes. So this doesn't help...

Comment: I'm not sure where that would happen. There are no dollar signs in text exposed to the shell, only in the output of the pipeline. In all the attempts you posted, you would need `echo 'Bla$bla' | sed ...` so that `$bla` isn't expanded before `echo` even runs, but you should not need to process the output of the initial pipeline.

Comment: Maybe it's a misunderstanding - the files have $-signs in their name and surely need to be listed in the output bash script. With your version, they are just inside quotes. But when I execute that script (to really delete the files), all un-escaped $ signs are read as variable - since the script is run without arguments, they just expand to an empty string. Then the files "bla$1.class" and "bla$1$2.class" will both be translated to "bla.class" for the rm command

Comment: Oh, sorry, right. Just change the double-quotes to single-quotes in the output to `REMOVEOLDFILE.sh`.

Answer (score 8):

The correct way to escape a dollar sign in regular expressions for sed is **double-backslash**. Then, for creating the escaped version in the output, we need some additional slashes:

```
cat filenames.txt | sed "s/\\$/\\\\$/g" > escaped-filenames.txt
```

Yep, that's four backslashes in a row. This creates the required changes: a filename like `bla$1$2.class` would then change to `bla\$1\$2.class`.
This I can then insert into the full pipeline:

```
for i in $(diff -r old new 2>/dev/null | grep "Only in old" | cut -d "/" -f 3- | sed "s/: /\//g" | sed "s/\\$/\\\\$/g"; do echo "rm -f $i" >> REMOVEOLDFILES.sh; done
```

**Alternative to solve the background problem**

*chepner* posted an alternative to solve the backround problem by simply adding single-quotes around the filenames for the output. This way, the $-signs are not read as variables by bash when executing the script and the files are also properly removed:

```
for i in $(diff -r old new 2>/dev/null | grep "Only in old" | cut -d "/" -f 3- | sed "s/: /\//g"); do echo "rm -f '$i'" >> REMOVEOLDFILES.sh; done
```

(note the changed `echo "rm -f '$i'"` in that line)

Comment: No -- the correct way to escape a dollar sign *in a double-quoted string in the shell*  is to put two backslashes. In single quotes, a single backslash is correct and sufficient, and two backslashes is wrong.  Generally, unless you require the shell to interpolate variables and execute command substitutions, use single quotes. Use single quotes always when you can.

Comment: As tripleee says, here to escape `$` *both bash and sed* participate. For sed, BRE syntax in `info sed` use `'\$'` for a single dollar sign. For bash `info bash` 3.1.2.3 Double Quotes, "The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: ‘$’, ... ‘"’, ‘\’, or ‘newline’. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed ... are removed". So for the above `\\$`, bash first removes the 1st '\' and then sed read the 2nd '\' of the original string to escape and output `$`.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a nice answer directly in the edited question that helped me a lot - thank you!

I just want to add a bit of curious behavior that I stumbled across: matching against a dollar sign at the end of lines (e.g. when modifying PS1 in your .bashrc file). 
As a workaround, I match for additional whitespace.

```
$ DOLLAR_TERMINATED="123456 $"
$ echo "${DOLLAR_TERMINATED}" | sed -e "s/ \\$/END/"
123456END
$ echo "${DOLLAR_TERMINATED}" | sed -e "s/ \\$$/END/"
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: Invalid back reference
$ echo "${DOLLAR_TERMINATED}" | sed -e "s/ \\$\s*$/END/"
123456END
```

Explanation to the above, line by line:

- Defining DOLLAR_TERMINATED - I want to replace the dollar sign at the end of DOLLAR_TERMINATED with "END"
- It works if I don't check for the line ending
- It won't work if I match for the line ending as well (adding one more $ on the left side)
- It works if I additionally match for (non-present) whitespace

(My sed version is `4.2.2` from February 2016, bash is version `4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`, in case that makes any difference)

Comment: At first I thought your first echo `123456END` is missing the `$` because the echo ate it.  try `DOLLAR_TERMINATED='123456 $'` with apostrophe, and test with `echo ${DOLLAR_TERMINATED}` to make sure it is correct.

Comment: Your second echo had an exception because the `$$` got interpreted as your PID (a number) and sed didn't find a `(pattern)` with that back reference number.  You can check this with `echo "$$"`

Comment: You can also achieve this with `echo "${DOLLAR_TERMINATED}" | sed -e "s/ \\\$$/END/"`  The triple backslash is two to escape the backslash and one to escape the dollar. or with `echo "${DOLLAR_TERMINATED}" | sed -e 's/ \$$/END/'` using apostrophe so the shell doesn't need the escapes to pass what you want to sed.