# How to keep dollar sign within sed in the bash script?

Tags: string, bash

I am trying to find a way to escape the dollar sign within the `sed` command in a bash script. I have found here tons of answers that say that you need to put four backslashes in a row in order to escape the sign. I have also tried the version with two backslashes, but for some reason, I can't get it to work. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Let's say that you have a file called `aaa.txt` located in `/home/Documents`. The file has just only one line of text, which says `aaa`. I am trying to replace it using this command (please don't tell me that I can reference it in a different way than with line numbers because this is just a reduced example of something else I am doing):

```
sed -i "1ccd /home/userr/$PARAMETER/$METHOD" "/home/userr/Documents/aaa.txt"
```

The output that I get is this:

```
cd /home/userr/\/\
```

Which is not what I want. I want to have exactly this output, with dollar signs in the string:

```
cd /home/userr/$PARAMETER/$METHOD
```

What is the proper form of the string passed to the `sed` command to achieve this?

Comment: It worked with a single backslash for escaping on my bash shell `\$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the dollar sign with a backslash:

```
sed -i "1ccd /home/userr/\$PARAMETER/\$METHOD" "/home/userr/Documents/aaa.txt"
```

Documentation here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Escape-Character.html

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. But I am confused as to why do the other answers then say to use 4 of them, such as in this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506303/escape-dollar-sign-in-regexp-for-sed

Comment: I guess it's because it was part of a regex

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the double quotes so `sed` will not try and expand it. This `sed` should work without escaping needed.

```
$ sed -i '1ccd /home/userr/$PARAMETER/$METHOD' /home/userr/Documents/aaa.txt
```