# Linux operating system

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am a beginner at Linux and I'm trying to do a project which takes every line from a `file.txt` and replaces the third word with the first of each line. Here is my Shell code but it doesn't seem to work. It keeps replacing the third word with `$field1` and not what's in it.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=: read -r field1;do    
    sed -e 's/[^:]*[^:]/$field1/3'
done < file.txt
```

Comment: you might want to change the title of your question to something more relevant, like "using variable with sed not working" and in which case you might find this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151954/how-to-use-variables-in-a-command-in-sed

Comment: Your `sed` command consumes the rest of `file.txt` because you are not specifying an input file.  Use either a `while read` loop or `sed` (preferably the latter in most cases) but not both, unless they need to operate on separate streams or files.

Comment: thanks for the heads up!

Comment: You want to swap 3th and 1th or not, just 1th with 3th?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, this will replace in the same file:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read -r line
do
        first=`echo $line | awk -F':' '{ print $1 }'`
        last=`echo $line | awk -F':' '{ print $3 }'`

        echo $line | sed "s/$last/$first/"

done < file.txt
```

Input file :

```
ashish:is:good
navin:is:good
how:are:you
```

Output :

```
ashish:is:ashish
navin:is:navin
how:are:how
```

Comment: It doesn't help if I do that. I have to replace the third word with the first of each line. That bit will only print the fields.

Comment: replace, not exchange? correct?

Comment: ok, that works. but ultimately i have to replace those words in the file. not just print them on screen.

Comment: Your quoting is exactly wrong.  The colons are not shell metacharacters and thus do not require quoting, while the variables could contain shell metacharacters, irregular whitespace, etc and thus *need* to be quoted. (As an experiment, use input where one of the fields is an asterisk and nothing else to see the point proven.)

Comment: Quoting is not wrong but shouldn't have been used. Anyway thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @TdFn please check now. Tell me if you are still facing any issue.

Comment: @AshishK Great! It's perfect. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Make note of the single quotation marks. Place them around the field1 variable and so:

```
sed -e 's/[^:]*[^:]/'$field1'/3'
```

Comment: Nope. I don't know why but it only duplicates the fields. Not even replacing anything.