# Change a string in a line in file via a script and sed

Tags: regex, sed, evaluation

I have a script that restores db dump. As a parameter a database name is passed to this script. In a dump there is a following line:

```
ALTER DATABASE `previosDbName` CHARACTER ... ;
```

I have to change `previosDbName` to a value, passed as a parameter. I try to use `sed`, but it does not work. 
Here is a script:

```
echo $3

export updateValue="ALTER DATABASE \`$3\`"

echo $updateValue

sed -i 's/ALTER DATABASE `\(.*\)`/${updateValue}/' $4
```

Here how I run it:

```
./test.sh dbP dbN medi_6_0 full_path_to_test.sql
```

The output of the script tells us, that `updateValue` is a correct one:

```
medi_6_0
ALTER DATABASE `medi_6_0`
```

But the result string:

```
${updateValue} CHARACTER ...;
```

Instead of:

```
ALTER DATABASE `medi_6_0` CHARACTER ...;
```

I've also tried to use double quotes, but it did not help:

```
sed -i 's/ALTER DATABASE `\(.*\)`/"${updateValue}"/' $4
```

**Update:** Solution offered by @Sundeep helped:

```
sed -i 's/ALTER DATABASE `\(.*\)`/'"${updateValue}"'/' $4
```

None of solutions described in:
[How to use variables in a command in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151954/how-to-use-variables-in-a-command-in-sed)
Helped. As most of solutions (did not check all of them), offered in this topic.

Comment: double quotes within single quotes are just another character, it won't do variable substitution... try ``'s/ALTER DATABASE `\(.*\)`/'"${updateValue}"'/'``

Comment: Give a try to `sed -i -E "s/ALTER DATABASE (.*)/$updateValue/" $4`

Comment: @Sundeep, only your solution helped. Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use variables in a command in sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151954/how-to-use-variables-in-a-command-in-sed)

Comment: @BenjaminW., none of the solutions in that issue helped, I'll add it into the my original question

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19152302/3266847) does the exact same quoting as Sundeep's suggestion, not sure how it is different in your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sed -iE "s/(ALTER DATABASE \`).*(\`)/\1$3\2/" file.sql
```

- Use double quotes so that "$3" can be expanded by shell
- Escape the reverse quotes, otherwise it tells shells to execute the text between ` and ` as a command.

Answer (score 0):

To allow variable interpolation enclose *sed* expression with double quotes.
Also, backtick  ` sign has a special meaning. Everything between backticks is evaluated. So it should be escaped with a backslash `\`

```
...
export updateValue="$3"
sed "s/\(ALTER DATABASE\) \`.*\`/\1 \`$updateValue\`/" $4
...
```

The output:

```
ALTER DATABASE `medi_6_0` CHARACTER ... ;
```

Comment: @Alexandr, that's because you have used your old `updateValue` variable, use mine as specified in my answer

Answer (score 0):

`bash` variables  **can only expand inside double quotes**  and `backtick` needs to be escaped, i.e.:

```
sed -i "s/\(ALTER DATABASE\) \`.*\`/\1 \`$3\`/" $4
# ALTER DATABASE `medi_6_0` CHARACTER ... ;
```

---

Options:

```
-i     Edit files in-place (otherwise sends to stdout)
```