# Sed Md5Sum Command

Tags: ubuntu, sed, command-line, md5sum

I am attempting to write a script to update a file with the md5 of a jar file.

To get the md5, I can do the command:

```
 md5sum target/file1.jar | awk '{print $1;'}
```

This will print the md5 of the file. To use sed to replace the text ${md5}, I can do the command:

```
sed -i 's/${md5}/md5Output/g' File2.json
```

I would like to replace md5Output with the contents of the first command.

Is this possible? Basically the goal is to calculate the md5 of "File1" and place that md5 value in "File2"

Comment: Have you tried storing the result of your first command in a variable?

Comment: @StephenNewell I tried doing ">> variable" in the first command and using variable in the sed but it printing as a literal string not value of the variable :(

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151954/how-to-use-variables-in-a-command-in-sed

Comment: Note: the closing single quote in your awk command should be outside the curly braces.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Cyrus thanks for the references! Here is the complete answer for anyone who needs to do the same type of thing

```
 #!/bin/sh

 VARIABLE=$(md5sum target/file1.jar | awk '{print $1;}')
 sed -i "s|\${md5}|$VARIABLE|g" file2.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Sed One-liner :

```
$ sed -i  "s/\${md5}/$( md5sum target/file1.jar | awk '{print $1}' )/g" File2.json
```