# sed with multiple word string initialized with read command

Tags: sed

I 've got a file named file.conf containing:

this is the configuration text and this is the WORD to change.

Running:

```
sed -i 's/WORD/"ONE TWO"/g' file.conf
```

I will have file.conf modified:

this is the configuration text and this is the "ONE TWO" to change.

now if I make a script, using read:

```
read -p 'word to change' TEXT -> "ONE TWO"
echo $TEXT -> "ONE TWO" 
sed -i 's/WORD/'$TEXT'/g' file.conf
```

it does not work  with error message:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated `s' command
```

file.conf is not modified in this case.

but it works if I read $TEXT with only one word without spaces: "ONE" for instance.

Thanx folks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use variables in a command in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151954/how-to-use-variables-in-a-command-in-sed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quote variable like this:

```
sed -i 's/WORD/'"$TEXT"'/g' file.conf
```

Even safer:

```
sed -i 's/WORD/'"${TEXT}"'/g' file.conf
```