# Bulk update values in json files (writing files)

Tags: json

I have a set of JSON files in a local folder. What I want to do is change a particular string value in it, permanently. That means, deleting or modifying the old entry, writing a new one, and saving it.

Below is the format of the file:

```
{
  "name": "ABC #1",
  "description": "This is the description",
  "image": "ipfs://NewUriToReplace/1.png",
  "dna": "a56c520f57ba2a861de8c78099b4691f9dad6e87",
  "edition": 1,
  "date": 1641634646966,
  "creator": "Team Dreamlabs",
  "attributes": [
    {
```

I want to change ABA #1 to ABC #9501 in this file, ABC #2 to ABC #9502 in the text file, and so on. How do I do that on MAC in one go?

Comment: Open any text editor that allows you to search and replace.

Search for `#` and replace it with `#950`. I recommend vscode.dev if you don't have any.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the example, you are adding a value of 9500 to your integers after the symbol *#*.

Because this kind of a replacement is a kind of string operation, a cycle with command **sed** might be used:

```
for f in *.json; do sed -i.bak 's/\("name": "ABC #\)\([0-9]\)",/\1950\2",/' $f; done
```

it just replaces a single digit to the new composition... Despite it responses to the example, obviously, it would not work for more than number *#9*.

Then we need to use a bash function:

```
function add_number() { old_number=$(cat $1 | sed -n 's/[ ]*"name": "ABC #\([0-9]*\)",/\1/p'); new_number=$(($old_number+9500)); sed -i.bak "s/\(\"name\": \"ABC #\)\([0-9]*\)\",/\1${new_number}\",/" $1; }; for f in *.json; do add_number $f ; done
```

The function *add_number* extracts the integer value, then adds a desired number to it and then replaces content of the file.

For both extraction and replacing the *sed* is used again.

At extraction flag *-n* allows to limit the amount of lines at *sed* output and mode *p* prints the result of replacement. Also, we do not want spaces symbols to pass into this assignment.

At replacement double quotes used in order to enable the bash to use the variable value inside of *sed*. Also, the real quotes are masked.

Regarding addition from the comment below, in order to make replacement in another line with tag *edition* (and using the same number), just a new replacement *sed* operation should be added with amended regular expression to fit this line.

Finally, the overall code in a better look:

```
function add_number() {
  old_number=$(cat $1 | sed -n 's/[ ]*"name": "ABC #\([0-9]*\)",/\1/p')
  new_number=$(($old_number+9500))
  sed -i.bak "s/\(\"name\": \"ABC #\)[0-9]*\",/\1${new_number}\",/" $1
  sed -i.bak "s/\(\"edition\": \)[0-9]*,/\1${new_number},/" $1
}
for f in *.json
  do add_number $f
done
```

Those previous answers helped me to write this code:

- [using variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19152051/17867255) inside of *sed*
- [assigning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93676) the variable

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved half my problem, but if you see my code, I missed another part which says **"edition": 1,** which I missed. Need to change that also (adding 9500) ... it will be great if you can help me change that under the same code. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @DebashisDey, no problem, I edited the final code to meet your request. Please check. NB: the _*.bak_ files might be removed in a batch later using command like `rm *.json.bak`

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to manipulate your JSON files on more than just this one occasion, then you might want to consider using tools that are designed to accomplish such tasks with ease.

One popular choice could be [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) which is a "lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor" that "has zero runtime dependencies" and is also available for OS X. By using jq within your shell, the following would be one way to accomplish what you have asked for.

Adding the numeric value `9500` to the number sitting in the field called `edition`:

```sh
jq '.edition += 9500' file.json
```

Interpreting a part of a string as number, adding again `9500` to it, and recomposing the string:

```sh
jq '.name |= ((./"#" | .[1] |= "\(tonumber + 9500)") | join("#"))' file.json
```

On the whole, iterating over your files, making both changes at once, writing to a temporary file and replacing the original on success, while having the value to be added as external variable:

```sh
v=9500
for f in *.json; do jq --argjson v $v '
  .edition += $v | .name |= ((./"#" | .[1] |= "\(tonumber + $v)") | join("#"))
' "$f" > "$f.new" && mv "$f.new" "$f"
done
```

[Here](https://jqplay.org/s/2-dAhfqxNB) is an online "playground for jq", set up to simulate the application of my code from above to three imaginary files of yours. Feel free to edit the jq filter and/or the input JSON in order to see what could be possible using jq.