# Replace a string with a variable using sed

Tags: bash, sed, substitution

I have this string in my file

```
$vnet_address
```

And i have in my bash run time this variable which i want to replace my string with:

```
$vnet_address=10.1.0.0/16
```

I get an error when i run this command:

```
sed -i "/\$vnet_address/ s//$vnet_address/"
```

And i believe it is because of the slash character '/' in my variable.

How to go about it?

Comment: In attach dupe 1st 2 answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/19152051/5866580 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/19152302/5866580 will work in your case, we need to just put string and variable names in place of the shown examples, Logic is same where it shows how to escape a dollar string and how to use a shell variable in `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```bash
sed -i "s,\\\$vnet_address,${vnet_address}," file
```

Note:

- The regex delimiter character is replaced with `,`
- The `$` is properly escaped with a literal `\` character

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/6jARVN):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='$vnet_address'
vnet_address=10.1.0.0/16
sed "s,\\\$vnet_address,${vnet_address}," <<< "$s"
# => 10.1.0.0/16
```