# Postgres String FIlter using linux sed command

Tags: postgresql, sed

this is my postgres connection for an Nodejs application. Can you show me how to replace "password": "******" using sed command? My current sed filter is working but that's wrong. Pls

```
POSTGRES_DB={"username":"postgres","password":"admin*****","database":"*****","host":"10.125.208.15","port":"5432","dialect":"postgres"}
```

```
That is my filter
```

```bash
's/"password":"..........."*/"password":"12345"/g'
```

That is output:

```
POSTGRES_DB={"username":"postgres","password":"12345","database":"****","host":"10.125.208.15","port":"5432","dialect":"postgres"}
```

Comment: What do you expect? admin12345?

Comment: Yes @lojza password won't be static since it's rotatiing. How can I replace the old one with new one using sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help:

```
sed 's/"password":"[^"]*"/"password":"admin123"/g'
```

Your password should be double quote free
This command substitute (`s`) this phrase `"password":"[^"]*"` with this one `"password":"admin123"` globally (`g`) - replace all matches

Where `[^"]` means any character expect double quote and `*` means random count

Comment: @lozja that is really working with admin123. But it's not working with ${PASSWORD} variable. The output is showing like this. -- POSTGRES_DB={"username":"postgres","password":"${PASSWORD}","database":"acl-dev","host":"10.125.208.15","port":"5432","dialect":"postgres"}.. Can u help me pls?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151954/how-to-use-variables-in-a-command-in-sed