# Linux command line for find & replace not working

Tags: php, linux

Im having an issue with this code in the command line:

```
sed -i 's/row['email']/_SESSION['nen']/g' /var/www/v2-stage/v2-stage/add_on/change_password.php
```

For some reason i think it isnt working since the 'email'
but that is how the code is & i cant change it.
Also im running it through the shell_exec for php. but i tried it directly and it wasnt working as well.

any ideas?

Comment: you'd need to escape your inner quotes

Comment: Look at the color of the highlighted code. Notice anything? You're trying to use single quotes inside of a single-quoted string.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart *"For some reason i think it isnt working since the 'email'"* I think they're well aware of it

Comment: *"It is not working"* is not a good problem statement. Possible duplicate of [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/56041), [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407523/608639), [How do I escape double and single quotes in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7517632/608639), [How to escape single quote in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24509214/608639), etc.

Comment: Okay but i dont know how to escape my inner quotes this is why i posted the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have `'` in your command, you need to use double quote `"` for `sed`.

Any char except `'` will be literal (which means the `\` will be literal, too), so you can rewrite your command as

```
sed -i "s/row\['email'\]/_SESSION['nen']/g" /var/www/v2-stage/v2-stage/add_on/change_password.php
```

If you write your command in a text editor (or notice the color on stackoverflow), the syntax highlight will help you determine the correctness of your command.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. the `[` and `]` should be escaped. Updated.