# using sed to replace ' character with \'

Tags: sed

I have a string that goes like this `abcd'efgh\ ijkl\ mnop`

I want to make the string into `abcd\'efgh\ ijkl\ mnop`

`sed 's/\'/\\\'/g` didn't work

Comment: You were on right path, you need to just escape `'`(single quote) and your substitution part will work then. Since you are on right track for substituting `'` with `\'` only thing is you need to escape `'`. There are many answers given in attached dupe link for reference the same.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Wiktor convinced me that it was not the same question but that's too much even for me. Now take it to meta if you want that deleted. Over

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, you could mention that reason that convinced you, so that I/we could be aware of that also. I haven't said or flagged anything to delete this etc. I believe with due respect we could request to know the reason of reopening of you it could be told, thank you. Note: if we see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/24751341/5866580 it exactly does same thing what is given in this post's answer in terms of escaping `'`.

Comment: Posting these comments again here for users and OP. Also this particular answer in 2nd attached dupe link(https://stackoverflow.com/a/24751341/5866580) gives exact way `"'"` of escaping `'` in `sed` posted in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed 's/'"'"'/\\&/g'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/R4BsBd):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s="abcd'"'efgh\ ijkl\ mnop'
sed 's/'"'"'/\\&/g' <<< "$s"
# => abcd\'efgh\ ijkl\ mnop
```