# How to replace string with double quotes using sed

Tags: sed

I have a string in my yaml file

```
prod:1.2.3"
```

In my bash

```
OLD_VERSION=1.2.3
NEW_VERSION=1.2.4
```

but I don't want to use

```
sed -i "" "s|$OLD_VERSION|$NEW_VERSION|g" test.txt
```

because there might be a chance that there would be 1.2.3 in some other place.So what I want to do instead is

replace `1.2.3"` with `1.2.4"`

how to add `"` in sed command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I escape slashes and double and single quotes in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517632/how-do-i-escape-slashes-and-double-and-single-quotes-in-sed)

Comment: Incorrect dupe because OP is trying to use shell variables in `sed` that need escaping in shell before they are evaluated in shell. Presence of starting `:` and ending `"` is also specific to this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed "s/:${OLD_VERSION//./\\.}\"/:${NEW_VERSION//./\\.}\"/g" file.yml

prod:1.2.4"
```

For the given values of the 2 variables it will execute this command:

```
sed 's/:1\.2\.3"/:1\.2\.4"/g' file.yml
```

- `${OLD_VERSION//./\\.}`: Replaces each dot with `\.` as dot matches any character
- `:` before this string and `"` after this will make sure that we match exact string `:1.2.3"` instead of `11.2.3` or `1.2.33`