# Could bash use non printing character as quote?

Tags: bash, printing, quotes

This question originates from one use case, replace `"` with `''`, latex quirk.

I usually use `'` (single quote) to enclose the script if there is `"` (double quote) inside, and vise verse. However, in this case, both single quote and double quote appear in this script, and I had google to find the proper way to handle it. This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91110/how-to-match-a-single-quote-in-sed) provides the solution. The following is the right, but not very readable solution.

```
sed 's!"!'\'''\''!' {filename}
```

After making it work, I began to think that this awkwardness comes from this quoting mechanics. Therefore, is it possible to use non printing character as the quote? Then, we don't need to escape quote any more.

Comment: for some definition of "right": you're missing the ending delimiter for `s!!!`

Comment: Sorry I don't get what the fuss is all about. What's wrong with `sed "s/\"/''/g"`? It's much nicer than yours and is very natural once you understand how double quotes work.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Cool! I didn't even realize this could be so simple. I will test it when I get home. Similarly, `sed 's!"!\'\'!'` should do the trick as well, right?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf My understanding was wrong. We couldn't just escape `'` using backslash inside `''`directly. On the first lesson on shell programming, we were told that string inside `''` is interpreted literally.

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you have single and double quotes, and here-docs and here-strings: You could do:

```
sed_script=$(cat << 'END'
s/"/''/g
END
)
sed "$sed_script" filename
```

Comment: `sed -f - filename <<'END' ... 'END'` will work as well (read the script directly from standard input, instead of stuffing it into a shell parameter).

Comment: @chepner I am not able to get it work, using your solution. `sed -f - <filename> <<'END' s!"!''! 'END'` is what I used, and bash thinks it's unterminated quoting, prompts `/` when I hit `Enter`.

Comment: Don't quote the last `END`. Quoting the first `END` give it the magic power.

Comment: Why on earth did I quote the closing `END`?

Comment: @glennjackman @chepner It seems both of you get it working. Unlucky me. `sed -f - <filename> <<'END' s,",'', END` still doesn't work, leaving me with `/` when I hit Enter.