# Sed regular expression pattern to replace in CSS - adding OR check within

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have the following CSS `background-image` rules wherein I want the URL replaced with a new domain (you know, for the sake of loading images via a cookie-less domain):

1. `background-image : url(/image/test.png);`
2. `background-image : url("/image/test.png");`
3. `background-image : url('/image/test.png');`

I can catch the quotes before `/image` and then replace the URL correctly with the following `sed` expression:

```
local someVar=123
local replace='url\("\/\/img.mydomain.com\/'"$someVar"'\1\")'
sed -E 's,url\(.(.+).\),'"$replace"',g' file.css
```

The snippet

```
url\(.
```

takes care of the quote (single or double) in the URL string. But if the quotes are not there (first example above), the regex will obviously fail. What would be the correct regex to check for this?

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
local someVar=123
local replace='url\("\/\/img.mydomain.com\/'"$someVar"'\1\")'
sed -E 's,url\((\'|\")(.+)(\'|\")\),'"$replace"',g' file.css
```

and it just throws error: `` syntax error near unexpected token `)' ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this answer ([How to match a single quote in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91110/how-to-match-a-single-quote-in-sed)), you should use another pair of single quote:

```
local someVar=123
local replace='url\("\/\/img.mydomain.com\/'"$someVar"'\1\")'
sed -E 's,url\(('\''|\")(.+)('\''|\")\),'"$replace"',g' file.css
```

For better readability, you can use square brackets instead of the parentheses, and you can just put the double quote without escaping it.

```
sed -E 's,url\(['\''"]?([^'\'']+)['\''"]?\),'"$replace"',g' file.css
```

Comment: How do I correctly match "background-image : url(/image/test.png);" where the quotes are missing?

Comment: Cool! That worked fine. But when I use the above in the following case: 
url('/images/test.png'), 
it gives me an output that reads as:  
url("//img.mydomain.com/123/images/test.png' "); 
There's a trailing ' after "png"

Comment: Hmm, we must change the `(.+)` to not match the trailing quote. See my edits

Answer (score 3):

You can use this sed:

```
local someVar=123
local replace='\1\2//img.mydomain.com/'"$someVar"'\3\4'
```

**On Linux Use this sed command:**

```
sed -r "s~(url\()(['\"]?)(.*)$2(\);)~$replace~" file.css
```

**On OSX Use this sed command:**

```
sed -E "s~(url\()(['\"]?)(.*)$2(\);)~$replace~" file.css
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
background-image : url(//img.mydomain.com/123/image/test.png);
background-image : url("//img.mydomain.com/123/image/test.png");
background-image : url('//img.mydomain.com/123/image/test.png');
```

Comment: If I use the "-r" option, I get an "illegal option" error. Without the "-r", I get: "s~(url\()(['"]?)(.*?)(\ ...": \2 not defined in the RE

Comment: Is it OSX that you are using?

Comment: So sorry, I should have asked earlier. Just updated the answer with OSX sed command as well.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. This time it's a different error: "s~(url\()(['"]?)(.*?)(\ ...": RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid

Comment: No I had removed `.*?` command is this: `sed -E "s~(url\()(['\"]?)(.*)$2(\);)~$replace~" file.css`

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad! Works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```
someVar=123
replace='\/\/img.mydomain.com\/'"$someVar"''
sed  -E 's,(\/.*\/[a-z.]+),'"$replace"'\1,g' file.css
```

Output:

```
background-image : url(//img.mydomain.com/image/test.png);
background-image : url("//img.mydomain.com/image/test.png");
background-image : url('//img.mydomain.com/image/test.png');
```