# Using sed to configure file for travis build

Tags: shell, sed, travis-ci

I'm trying to change a php config file by adding an entry at the end to allow travis build by adding sqlite file path:

```
sh -c "if [ '$DB' = 'sqlite' ]; then sed -i "s/\?>/\$config['db']['path'] = 'sqlite.db3';\n?>/" etc/volkszaehler.conf.php; fi;"
```

Should result in a config file ending like this:

```
<?php
//.. various other options
$config['db']['path'] = 'sqlite.db3';
?>
```

Instead, keep running into shell errors:

```
/home/travis/build.sh: line 222: /$config[db][path]: Permission denied
```

or on cygwin:

```
sh: / etc/volkszaehler.conf.php; fi;: No such file or directory
```

What is the correct quoting/escaping to achieve the purpose?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Not sure: Using worker: worker-linux-5-2.bb.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-13 (https://travis-ci.org/andig/volkszaehler.org/jobs/14411860)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a quoting problem.  I'd try something like this:

```
sh -c '
  if [ "$DB" = "sqlite" ]; then
    sed -i "s/\?>/\$config[\'db\'][\'path\'] = \'sqlite.db3\';\n?>/" etc/volkszaehler.conf.php
  fi'
```

If the system supports it, I'd also remove the `sh -c` and the outermost quotes.

Comment: travis ci seems to need the sh -c for whatever reason. Finally ended up with:

 sh -c "if [ '$DB' = 'sqlite' ]; then sed -i 's/\?>/\$config['\''db'\'']['\''path'\'']\ =\ '\''sqlite.db3'\''\n?>/' etc/volkszaehler.conf.php; fi;"

from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91110/how-to-match-a-single-quote-in-sed