# sed string replacement containing special characters

Tags: sed

I have an input file -- "3dchess.sh" -- whose content is something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
Package=3dchess
Popcon=48
Section=universe

Comment=3D chess for X11
Exec=3Dc
```

---

I need to replace the "Comment" tags from:

```
Comment=3D chess for X11
```

to:

```
Comment='<span size="xx-large">3D chess for X11</b>'
```

---

I have tried this, but it doesn't work in my case:

```
sed -i ':Comment=:s:Comment=:Comment='<span size="xx-large">:g;/Comment=/s/$/</b>'/' $HOME/3dchess.sh
```

Comment: The problem found for me is: the single quote in Comment=' and </b>' fail also the / between < >, how to solve it?

Comment: You can escape the slashes in the search/replace pattern (`s/.../<\/b>/`) or use another regexp delimiter (`s|...|</b>|`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
echo "Comment=3D chess for X11" | \
  sed  's|Comment=|&'\''<span size="xx-large">|; s|Comment=.*|&</b>'\''|'
```

- reference: [How to match a single quote in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91110/how-to-match-a-single-quote-in-sed)

---

This

`Comment=3D chess for X11`

will become

`Comment='<span size="xx-large">3D chess for X11</b>'`

---

EDIT: To the best of my abilities, this is my `sed` explanation for:

```
's|Comment=|&'\''<span size="xx-large">|; s|Comment=.*|&</b>'\''|'
```

Use sed (`s`) substitute command to replace an old string (`Comments=`) to new string (`&'\''<span size="xx-large">`; which is made up of the old string (`&`) + single quote `'\''` + another string (`<span size="xx-large">`)).

Then (`;`) do another sed (`s`) substitute command to replace an old string (`Comment=.*`; which is made up of a string (`Comments=`) + anything after that (`.*`)) to new string (`&</b>'\''`; which is made up of the old string (`&`) + another string (`</br>`) + single quote (`'\''`))

Comment: @davidva, added explanation :)