# sed escape double quotes within single quotes

Tags: regex, bash, nginx, sed

I'm trying to add a log format to nginx.conf inside a Docker container via sed. I'm issuing the following command:

```
sed -i -e"s/client_max_body_size 100M/client_max_body_size 100M;\n\tlog_format specialLog '$remote_addr forwarded for $http_x_real_ip - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
                                                                                                  '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                                                                                                  '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"'/" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

However it is giving me the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 105: unterminated `s' command
```

How can I escape the log_format command?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/206963/4258817

Comment: I copy/past your command and it works fine for me. What are your variables values ?

Comment: See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168862/why-does-sed-outputs-char-53-unterminated-s-command Do you have a line-break in your command? That might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
awk '1; /client_max_body_size 100M/{ print "some text" }' file
```

If you edit your question to show some sample input and expected output we can show you exactly how to replace `some text` with your real text.