# sed to remove lines starting with single quotes

Tags: sed

I have file (db-chk.txt) which has multiple rows which start with single quote and I would like to search for this pattern using bash "sed" and remove all those lines which start with single quote (').

Tried few option, but they don't work

```
$ sed '/^'-/d' db-check.txt -- This one don't work

$ sed '/^\'-/d' db-check.txt
```

e.g. Sample data from db-check.txt which i want to get these lines removed.

> ---[BLOCKED/-SESSION]--
>
> ----[SESSION/-COUNT]---

Comment: try with sed -i "/^'/d" db-check.txt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match a single quote in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91110/how-to-match-a-single-quote-in-sed)

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't have any parameter expansion in your sed command, you can use double quote (as mentioned in comment):

```
sed -i "/'^-/d" db-check.txt
```

If you don't want parameter expansion, use single quote:

```
sed -i '/^\x27-/d' db-check.txt
```

`\x27` is the hex code for the `'`